# Rewrite file from another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite file in another directory but it gives an error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /admin/posts/edit/1 was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
/public_html
    /admin
         /.htaccess
         /posts
```

I need to do this `www.example.com/admin/posts/edit/1`  from this  `www.example.com/admin/posts/edit.php?id=1`

I have this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^edit/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /admin/posts/edit.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: /admin/posts/edit.php?id=$1... yes.. it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `/admin/.htaccess` and place this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^posts/edit/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ posts/edit.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I  cannot do that becaouse I have users, categories etc. folders. I have to make it dinamicly